# SSRS Parameter Mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

Can you Create parameters in SSRS using MDX measures not dimension, to reword this question can you create a paramter using fact table measure

**Explanation**

i have 2 measures 
[Measures].[PTO Holiday Hours] and [Measures].[PTO Vacation] 
i need to have a drop down parameter of those 2 measures is it possible ?
where if one measure paramter is selected it will display the users with   [Measures].[PTO Vacation] or [Measures].[PTO Holiday Hours]  based on selection ?

Comment: Another possibility is retrieve both measures from SSAS then use an IIF expression in the SSRS textbox to decide which to display.

Comment: Thanks @GregGalloway, sounds like another good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a parameter, lets call it "myoptions" with those 2 options

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
|      Labels       |             Value              |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
| PTO Holiday Hours | [Measures].[PTO Holiday Hours] |
| PTO Vacation      | [Measures].[PTO Vacation]      |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Create an expression for your query and either select one measure or another.

```
="WITH MEMBER X AS "+Parameters!myOptions.Value.ToString()+" SELECT {X} on 0, (...) on 1 FROM (...) "
```

Comment: Thank you Mxix for the quick response. Your solution sounds great, hope i'm not asking too much but can you please be a little more detailed. where im i applying that expression inside the parameter (myoptions)?

Comment: Sorry wasn't very clear... The expression would be your MDX query for your dataset.

Comment: Thank you mxix you have been very helpful

Comment: Not a problem @GraeshamMuchabaya if it did answer your question don't forget to mark it as answer.